# Accessing Shader Node Group inputs and outputs in Blender 4.0

Tags: python, shader-nodes

I'm making a script to compile libraries of jpegs into corresponding shaders. I want to tidy up things a bit by making a Shader Group Node.
I have managed to create the Group Node and it's corresponding Node Tree. But, as I understand, in Blender 4.0 its inputs and outputs cannot be accessed anymore like this:

`input_socket = groupTree.inputs.new('NodeSocketFloat', 'Input')`

I haven't been able to find the new way to access them.

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer in the new python API:

`tree.interface.new_socket(name="My Input", in_out='INPUT')`

Comment: FYI, "node groups' section here : https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Reference/Release_Notes/4.0/Python_API